# Using A Web API for Business Logic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

My web application needs to be able to go and get all my projects from Paymo http://api.paymo.biz/

I am familiar with JSON and XML, but what I'm wondering is, how does one interact with the api (make calls to it).

I would ideally like to make a class in ASP .Net such as PaymoManager(int apikey....)

From there I can wrap the functionality I need. I just need to understand, how do I call functions of the API and how do I get the response. I am not familar with web apis.

---

Edit: Could you give me an example of this, even with some abstract url. I need this done server side in a CS file.

Basically a simple example that calls someurl.com/somerequest and then how do you receive the JSON or XML... how does this work in terms of a class. I want this in a class.

Comment: You call the URL, receive the XML and use it.  I'm a little confused as to what answer you're looking for.

Comment: Could you give me an example of this, even with some abstract url. I need this done server side in a CS file.

Comment: Basically a simple example that calls someurl.com/somerequest and then how do you receive the JSON or XML... how does this work in terms of a class. I want this in a class.

Comment: Have you read the documentation you linked to? It seems fairly straightforward. Work your way through the examples, and if you get stuck on one in particular, revise your question to describe what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: I just want to do it right. I understand how to put the url together. But then how do I send a request and receive a response in my cs code file. I don't want to use javascript...

Comment: The only examples are in php.

Comment: Is the endpoint a web service? If so, you could use the Add Web Reference dialog in Visual Studio to generate a client for you. Otherwise you may have to use the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class to POST and download data to/from the server.

Comment: Well, how would a typical website interact with an api on the server side? I cannot find any examples in asp .net.

Comment: It all depends on how the api is defined. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.paymo.biz/docs/misc.overview.html

> To perform an action using the Paymo API, you need to send a request
>   to the Paymo webservice specifying a method and some arguments, and
>   will receive a formatted response.

This means that you can use [WebClient to download a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx) from a url:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string reply = client.DownloadString (address);
```

Depending on the format you specify, you can parse the reply as [XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532.aspx) or [JSON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316.aspx).

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(reply);

// where ReplyType is a class that defines public 
// properties matching the format of the json string
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
ReplyType abc = serializer.Deserialize<ReplyType>(reply);
```

Comment: How can I check for failure? Does this throw some sort of exception?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET 4.5, you might consider using [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) like so:

```
static async void Main()
    {
    try 
    {
      // Create a New HttpClient object.
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

      // fill in the details in the following string with your own KEY & TOKEN:
      string requestUrl = "https://api.paymo.biz/service/paymo.auth.logout?api_key=API_KEY&format=JSON&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN"
      HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl );
      response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
      string responseBodyJSON = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      // Above three lines can be replaced with new helper method in following line 
      // string body = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

      Console.WriteLine(responseBodyJSON );
      // Now you can start parsing your JSON....

    }  
    catch(HttpRequestException e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!"); 
      Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ",e.Message);
    }
  }
```